# How to Import images to a multi store Magento website thorugh CSV file?

Tags: csv, ce-1.9.0.0

I am running a Magento 1.9.1 website, which is a multi-store website.My need is to import images to each particular store .My stores are Sports,Music and default.
For eg:- my products are sku1 and sku2.
Sku1 have some images in which some of them need to be displayed in Sports store and some of them need to be displayed in Music store also.
We need same thing for the Product Sku2 too.
How to set my CSV for that?Is it possible to do with csv Dataflow import process?

Please help me to find a solution for the same

Answer (score 3):

You have to define the storeview, the information is for.

Just add a column with the head _store to your csv and write in it the storeview code.

check the link below

http://www.integer-net.com/2012/04/04/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/

Comment: My problem is partially solved.Default store view is okay now.But my other stores view have the same image configuration settings that same as the default store view. "Use Default Value" check box is already checked for all store views in the case of images.I have to used  "_media_is_disabled" as store view specific not the default value..It would be great if you can check my CSV file that I created for my last import process and please correct the same.My CSV file is attached in this link [link] (http://salviatech.com/import-20150505045515-1_multi_store_img_exporting_procedsss_UTF8.csv)

Comment: check replacing store with _store

Comment: Still I have the same problem persist.

Comment: @Dev  How can i import images using by magmi for my multi store Magento? As a single store its working fine, after added additional store, magmi image not working.  csv screen shot : https://snag.gy/Ju6MbK.jpg if i did any error, pls let me know and demo CSV sheet.

Comment: @MPchan you should mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think dev provides the right answer for your question, but as an addition, I could highly recommend using Magmi for imports, you can do multistore import and it is amazingly fast and great.

Comment: I do want to give the Magmi suggestion a +1. But everything can be done using the standard import/export tools. There is also a [free extension](https://github.com/henryhayes/Sandfox_ImportExportFix) that makes error checking more rubust.